# TensorFlow keras Text classification: Applying model to score a word

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp

The data i am using is BBC News Paper headlines , with its genre description category.
( Sport , Business, Politics, Tech , Entertainment ).

I am having trouble with interpreting the output after training the model and doing an assessment of the loss. I want to say which category out of the 5 ( Sport , Business, Politics, Tech , Entertainment ) the model would score a new sentence i give the model.

I know the model final layer outputs 5 categories+ 1 for no result :
resulttf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation='softmax') .

Below is my attempt, I get the tokens. the predictions class are all 1 and the model predict gives me a matrix of (Number of letters in my test sentence x the number of classification categories)

for many examples i get this '1 1 1 1 1' answer which even when i try different category of words.

[image]

Comment: Could you include a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find the solution to the issue by changing how i input a new sentence. 
The key was to add it in this format.

sentence = ["""Olympic  games"""]

I then get one key reflecting one word
and a score classification per sentence/paragraph.